# Java Program to return latest file in a folder matching content

Tags: java, file

I am writing a program in Java which will parse files from a folder and then return the latest file matching a string.

For example, in a folder with 4 files (4th file with latest modified date). I am now writing a program which will return the latest file containing the string and not just the latest file in the folder. In the illustration below, I expect the Java code to return file 3 and not file 4.

[image]

Here is the code which I am attempting and am getting null. I am debugging the code now which not sure why it just does not enter while loop.

The below code works.

```
    public class LatestFileMatchingString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File directory = new File("testDataFolder");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
        long lastModifiedTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        File chosenFile = null;

        if (files != null)
        {
            for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime)
                {

                    try {
                        int count = 0;
                        FileReader fileIn = new FileReader(file);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileIn);
                        String line;
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                            String newLine = scanner.nextLine();
                            System.out.println(newLine);
                            if((newLine.contains("JAVASTRING"))) {
                                chosenFile = file;
                                lastModifiedTime = file.lastModified();
                                System.out.println("This file has string " + file);
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The latest File with matching string is : " + chosenFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `directory` is actually the one you want? You can check that by printing `directory.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Thanks Schred directory is fine, as I can see the code traversing through the file whilst debugging. The problem is this line - while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) which for some strange reason is misbehaving.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how readers work. All I can do is to suggest using a scanner instead of a reader and saying `while(scanner.hasNextLine()) { line = scanner.nextLine(); //... }`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:maven]?

Comment: Have you checked if the execution is actually entering the loop? Do the files really contain "JavaString"? Remember that contains is case sensitive.

Comment: @Joni took the words out of my mouth. It looks like this could be a simple case of case sensitivity.

Comment: Also @JavaMan make sure you're closing your Closeable object(s).

Comment: @Joni, Jason - it was me been stupid. You guys are absolutely right, it was just a case of case sensitivity. I have also modified my code to use scanner as Schred suggested. I will update the working code in my question above.

Comment: @Andreas - Apologies, removed Maven tag.

Comment: Don't use `Scanner` for line-reading. It is very slow compared to `BufferedReader`. --- Also, I would recommend you sort the file names in descending date order, so you can stop scanning files as soon as you find a match. Much faster that way.